# Efficiently outputing a table

Tags: php

I am trying to wrap my head around a clear/efficient way of turning an array of arrays into a table.  Originally I was building the table horizontally, my example being a list of events organized by city.  For example:
First, Toronto will have 5 events, so its row had 5 cells, each with event information.  Next, Vancouver will have 7 events, so its row would have 7 cells.

This was very easy to do, but now I have been asked to turn it so the rows become columns.  So now there will be 'Toronto' and 'Vancouver' in the top row, with each row after being an event, until it ends with Vancouver events sticking out lower that Toronto events.  My first idea is to find the array with the longest length and use it's count in an IF statement (in this case Vancouver).  Is there a more efficient way of doing this using some PHP commands that I probably don't know.

**edit**

So each event will have a name, checkbox (to accept the event) and an input box to add a number of guests.  This is for an admin portal to create invites so creating something fancy isn't necessary and it is requested to see all the events at the same time.  The number of locations will not change very often (but can change) and the number of events will never exceed 15, but will change fairly often

Comment: Could we see an example of the data structure? or Query you're using to pull the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more of a UI thing then a PHP thing, but here's a solution... you split up the cities... say 5 per table.

Those are your columns..

```
[Toronto] [New York] [California] [Milwaukee] 
[Event 1] [Event 2 ] [ Event 3  ] [Event 4  ]
[Event x] [Event x ] [          ] [         ]
```

Then, when you rollover each event, the event information is presented in a tooltip/popup or something.

That would organize the information better I think.  If Event 1, etc have enough descriptive things.

Just an idea.